# Run c++ programs with limited RAM

Tags: c++, performance, ram

I want to test the performance of different c++ programs, with focus on memory handling.
I'm working with Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux, and my pc has 12GB of RAM; since the amount of RAM is quite big for simple programs, I'm unable to tell the time difference between different memory handling choices.
For example, preallocating vs push back elements one by one leads to similar times. I think this is because, while pushing back elements, my pc rarely runs out of adiacent memory and it never needs to copy everything and deal with freelist. Am I wrong?

To solve the problem, I'm wondering if there is a way to limit a c++ program's RAM resources, and run it with just 1 or 2GB of RAM.

Comment: You could run your program in a virtual box of some kind. There you should be able to set the constraints you want.

Comment: You won't measure what you think you are.  Your OS implements demand-paged virtual memory, creating the illusion that your program has access to many more gigabytes of memory than are actually installed.  Regardless of the amount of RAM.  So it never runs out of "adjacent memory", less RAM merely keeps the swap busier.

Answer (score 1):

The ***ulimit*** command can help you.

You can use `ulimit -a` to see all set limits.

Then you can modify it, following this guide : [setting limits with ulimit](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2693414/setting-limits-with-ulimit.html).